# How to send automated response mail to sender in contact us form

Tags: magento2, email, contact-us

After submitting the contact us form in magento 2 I want to send a automated response mail to sender

I got somewhere solution for magento 1

```
1. Create custom event to fire once the contact form has been submitted.
2. Create another mail action in the same controller and call the mail action in the try block.


public function sendMailAction(){
$html="
put your html content here
blah blah

 ";
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('Your Name');
$mail->setToEmail('Youe Email');
$mail->setBody('Mail Text / Mail Content');
$mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
 $mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
 $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

try {
$mail->send();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
$this->_redirect('');
 }
 catch (Exception $e) {
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
 $this->_redirect('');
}
 }
```

But how to implement same thing in magento 2.